# how to add the value + 1 to an integer ? / android studio / firebase / java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

1. I get infinity. the number is constantly growing
2. Do I need to write? ---    finish();

how to sum money value in Firebase Realtime.

How can I sum a value with the existing node value?

```
save_test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        save();
    }
});




private void save() {

databaseRefBalanceInf = firebaseDatabase.getReference("users").child("test");

databaseRefBalanceInf.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot2) {
        try {

            Integer infBalance = snapshot2.getValue(Integer.class);
            databaseRefBalanceInf.setValue(infBalance + 1);

            // databaseRefBalanceInf.setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //empty
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        //empty
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: **Warning**: `catch (Exception e) { }` is a very bad idea. It swallows *any* exception it encounters. So it hides any bug within the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

> I get infinity. The number is constantly growing.

That's expected behavior. Why? It's because when you are using the [Query#addValueEventListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) method, it means that you are listening for real-time updates. This also means that every change that takes place in the at `databaseRefBalanceInf` reference, will always trigger the `onDataChange()` method. Since you are adding data inside the callback using:

```
databaseRefBalanceInf.setValue(infBalance + 1);
```

To the exact **same** reference you are listening to, the `onDataChange()` method is called over and over again, hence the behavior of "infinity".

To solve this, simply change the above method call to [Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)). This means that it will listen for changes **only** once.

P.S. If you want to read the value of `infBalance` and increment it by one based on that value, then I recommend you to use [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). If you only want to increment the value no matter what already exists in the database, then I recommend you to use  [atomic server-side increments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments).

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?